# Which of these answers are the equivalent of O_RDWR on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix

I have been given a list of the following check box containing all possible solutions to the question of choosing all true answers equivalent to O_RDWR on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. according to this list below

O_RDONLY

1

2

3

1 << 1

3 & 2

3 | 2

O_WRONLY

(O_RDONLY + O_WRONLY)

(O_RDONLY | O_WRONLY)

(O_RDONLY & O_WRONLY)

(O_RDONLY && O_WRONLY)

(O_RDONLY << 1)

(O_WRONLY << 1)

0

I have chosen 2 and (O_RDONLY | O_WRONLY) but am still getting errors

anyone who can help me with this?

Comment: Write a small program that compares all these expressions with `O_RDWR` and prints the result...

Comment: Andrew Henle has an excellent point. The OP assumes they are individual bits but that is not correct so the OP itself does not make sense - so any correct answer might be correct as per the OP, but it does not make sense either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look into bitwise operators.

```
O_RDWR is defined in fcntl.h and is equals to 2.
O_WRONLY = 1
O_RDONLY = 0

1 = 1
2 = 2
3 = 3
1 << 1 = 2
3 & 2 = 2
3 | 2 = 3
O_WRONLY = 1
(O_RDONLY + O_WRONLY) = 1
(O_RDONLY | O_WRONLY) = 1
(O_RDONLY & O_WRONLY) = 0
(O_RDONLY && O_WRONLY) = 0
(O_RDONLY << 1) = 1
(O_WRONLY << 1) = 2
0 = 0
```

Comment: Why not add `114598715 - 114598713`?  Or `sqrt( 4 )`? This answer is ***wrong***. Per [the Linux `open(2)` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html): "File access mode
       Unlike the other values that can be specified in flags, the
       access mode values `O_RDONLY`, `O_WRONLY`, and `O_RDWR` do not specify
       individual bits. ..."

Answer (score 4):

O_WRONLY = 1, O_RDONLY = 0 and O_RDWR = 2 so do the bitwise and find which statement gives you 2

have you got it it means 2, 1<<1, 3&2 and (O_WRONLY<<1) these can give you 2

Comment: Why not calculate the cube root of 8?  That's 2 also.  `O_RDWR` is defined as `O_RDWR`, not as some combination of other values.  Full stop.  Anyone arguing otherwise simply doesn't understand how the value is defined.  The fact that it **happens to be 2** is not relevant.  Downvotes merely demonstrate that lack.

Answer (score 2):

**None of them**.

The only equivalent to `O_RDWR` is `O_RDWR`.  `O_RDWR` is **not** a bitwise combination of individual bits.  Neither are `O_EXEC`, `O_RDONLY`, `O_SEARCH`, or `O_WRONLY`.

Per the [POSIX documentation for `open()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) (bolding mine):

> ... Applications shall specify **exactly one** of the first five values
> (file access modes) below in the value of oflag:
>
> ```
> O_EXEC
>     Open for execute only (non-directory files). The result is unspecified if this
>     flag is applied to a directory.
> O_RDONLY
>     Open for reading only.
> O_RDWR
>     Open for reading and writing. The result is undefined if this flag is applied to a FIFO.
> O_SEARCH
>     Open directory for search only. The result is unspecified if this flag is
>     applied to a non-directory file.
> O_WRONLY
>     Open for writing only.
> ```

Comment: I suspect that the question is about implementation-specific behavior... the "on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS" seems to me a giveaway. The only way to answer this question IMO is to either look in the headers and do the relevant math on the numerical values, or, more simply, write a program that does that.

Comment: @MatteoItalia But that won't mean anything - `O_RDWR` is not defined in terms of other bits - it's defined **as** `O_RDWR`, whatever that value may be.  If  `O_RDWR` may be able to be constructed from other flags, that's a coincidence that  isn't relevant to its defined value.  That'd be like saying `SIGSEGV` is `SIGINT + SIGKILL`.  The value might coincidentally match, but that's not what `SIGSEGV` ***is***.  `SIGSEGV` ***is*** `SIGSEGV` only.

Comment: This question is a great example of one of the huge divides in programming.  Many programmers are consumed by trying to get their programs to work.  But good programmers additionally insist that their programs work *for the right reasons*. Andrew's right: `O_WRONLY << 1` (or `SIGINT + SIGKILL` for `SIGSEGV`) might work, they might even work "perfectly well", but they do not work for the right reason, and so IMO they're just wrong, at least as wrong as if they didn't work at all.

Comment: I'm reminded of the line `kill(SIGHUP, 1);` I found years ago in some very old code that was trying to send `SIGHUP` to process id 1, the `init` process.  It worked — it had been working for years — but it was comically wrong, and I fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

2,
1<<1 also 00000001 shift left by 1 = 00000010 so, the value also 2 ,
3&2 also 2,
O_WRONLY << 1 also 2,
so this is the answer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

2, 1<<1 also 00000001 shift left by 1 = 00000010 so, the value also 2, 3&2 also 2, O_WRONLY << 1 also 2,

final answer :

1. 2
2. 1<<1
3. 3&2
4. O_WRONLY << 1